# Openscenegraph not generating viewer examples

Tags: cmake, openscenegraph

I downloaded the latest release of OpenSceneGraph (3.4.0) (zipped file and latest github repository).
I am trying to generate at least the osgviewerQT and osgViewerWX examples. They are contained in the examples folder, but after using CMake to generate everything, the only osgviewer-Example is osgviewerGLUT. Also `osgqt.lib` and `osgwx.lib` are missing in the lib-folder after building the generated projects via `ALL_BUILD` and `INSTALL`.

In CMake I made sure that all wx and Qt5 (using Qt5.6) folders are found. But still no examples after generating. Any ideas?

Comment: Has CMake found Qt and Wx?

Comment: For wx I had to manually point to the include- and lib-folders, but Qt was found automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The CMake rules for OpenSceneGraph include a BUILD_OSG_EXAMPLES toggle. Did you select that option in CMake?

Comment: Yes, of course. It generated a lot of examples, but there are a lot missing among osgqt and osgwx. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the BUILD_OSG_APPLICATIONS toggle and you will see the applications (osgarchive, osgconv, osgfilecache, osgversion, osgviewer, present3D) in the bin directory.

[image: How to set BUILD_OSG_APPLICATIONS]

In order to compile osgViewerQt you need to set QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE to the location where you have qmake (typically in the directory bin of Qt). This varialbe, when not just found, is available under "Ungrouped Entries".

[image]

After setting such url, CMake will be able to find Qt; then, enabling BUILD_OSG_APPLICATIONS and BUILD_OSG_EXAMPLES, it will also build other applications related to Qt.